# How to perform an upsert in Mongoose looking for an embedded document?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

```
SocialProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema
  source:
    type: String
    enum: ['twitter','facebook']
    lowercase: true
  user_id: String
  profile_url: String
  primary:
    type: Boolean
    default: true
  added_on:
    type: String
    default: Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000.0)

UserProfileSchema  = new mongoose.Schema
    socialProfiles: [SocialProfileSchema]
    added_on:
      type: String
      default: Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000.0)
```

That's my Schema. To check for a specific `user_id` within a `SocialProfileSchema` and then perform an upsert seems like a gargantuan task. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you can do an update if exists, otherwise insert:

Arguments for update are: findQuery, data, queryOptions, onComplete

```
var update = { data: "1", expires: 300 };
that.update({ session_id: sid }, { $set: update }, { upsert: true }, function(err, data) {
  callback.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

Comment: fyi you don't need to use callback.apply(...); you can simply use callback(...).

Answer (score -1):

How about a dbref? It will let you access the SocialProfiles directly instead of having to loop through a bunch of embedded objects

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html