# Embedded document becomes null in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have one embedded document as below:

```
var artist = new Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
      trim:true,
      required:'Please fill artist name'
        },
        role : {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            default: ''
        },
        isPrimary : {
            type: Boolean,
            trim: false,
        }
    });
```

and other document is as below:

```
var AlbumSchema = new Schema({
  language: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    artists: [artist],
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Album title',
        trim: true
    });
```

when I send request and princt req.body value than I get as below:

```
{
      title: 'Demo Add',
      artists:  
       '[{"name":"Ilesh","role":"Performer","isPrimary":true,"$$hashKey":"ob 
              ject:227"}]',
        language:'EN'
}
```

but as soon as I cast it to object as

```
var album = new Album(req.body);
```

and print album than I get result as below:

```
{
      title: 'Demo Add',
      artists: [],
      language: 'English' 
}
```

I don't  know why artists value becomes null during case.

**EDIT :**

```
exports.SaveAlbum = function(req,res){
        var album = new Album(req.body);
        var data = _.pick(req.body, 'type')
                , uploadPath = path.normalize('/album_uploads')
                , file = req.files.file;
        var user = req.user;
        album.cover_art_path = file.path;
        if (user) {
                var upsertData = album.toObject();
                delete upsertData._id;
                Album.update({_id: album.id}, upsertData, {upsert: true},function(err)
                {
                        if (err) {
                                return res.status(400).send({
                                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                                });
                }
                else {
                                res.json(album);
                }
                });
        } else {
            res.status(400).send({
                message: 'User is not signed in'
            });
        }

};
```

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: yes I am using mongoose

Comment: You are updating the _id ... I think that's not good!!

Comment: currently my issue is that I am not getting data from req.body to artists array. other than that this work as expected.

Comment: but you also make an update, and pass 
`var upsertData = album.toObject()` Are you sure that is running correctly with your parameters? I don´t know what you mean with upsert, etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267102/how-do-i-update-upsert-a-document-in-mongoose

Comment: you are adding an album.cover_art_path when the albumSchema does not have this property. Maybe that is making mongoose to not save the document? 
or maybe adding the second parameter to the callback function as seen here?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518059/how-to-perform-an-upsert-in-mongoose-looking-for-an-embedded-document

Comment: I have very big schema but for clearity I have put some of them properties in SO question.

Comment: I´ve found this: `Changed in version 3.0: When you execute an update() with upsert: true and the query matches no existing document, MongoDB will refuse to insert a new document if the query specifies conditions on the _id field using dot notation.`
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#mongodb30-upsert-id

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#mongodb30-upsert-id

Comment: HEY!! I SAW THAT!! `{_id: album.id}` <-- it tmust be  `{_id: album._id}` <-- maybe the combination with upsert:true makes it to not be inserted as the _id is not found!!!

Comment: if it´s that, i´ll change the solution to explain all

Comment: dude I have no any error and also no issue with upsert, The only issue I face that when I do var album = new Album(req.body) than it must contains artists value. but it is not.

Comment: that´s why your printed album after save does not contain the _id too, I guess...

Comment: then, what is the Album definition for `new Album` ?

Comment: maybe `album = new Album(angular.toJson(req.body, pretty));` could help? or something similar?  ** if using angular. , if not JSON.parse(req.body)

Comment: I did change my answer Check that method to show how I ´d leave the save method as far as I can guess to be ok

Comment: edited to use findOneAndUpdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the '' in the array as commented below. That was the problem in origin, when sending the req.body as told.

your req.body is:

```
{
      title: 'Demo Add',
      artists: '[{"name":"Ilesh","role":"Performer","isPrimary":true,"$$hashKey":"ob 
              ject:227"}]',
        language:'EN'
}
```

and it must be:

```
{
      title: 'Demo Add',
      artists: [{"name":"Ilesh","role":"Performer","isPrimary":true,"$$hashKey":"ob 
              ject:227"}],
        language:'EN'
}
```

This quotes are making the artists being a string, not an Array, and then it fails when saving.

Then, the solution is:

```
var album = new Album(req.body); 
album.artists = JSON.parse(req.body.artists);
```

Hope to help.

Thanks

Comment: Look then for the variable acting vas merge result (updated) and just add before the save comand the updated.markModified('artists')

Comment: from my question you can see my updted object has [] for artist so even after markModified it still blank.

Comment: you are adding ' ' to define the artist when putting. Are you sure you need those ' ' ?

I think it should be: 
`artists :[{"name":"Ilesh","role":"Performer","isPrimary":true,"$$hashKey":"ob 
              ject:227"}];`

Comment: that is default value and that will apply if I have nothing to name

Comment: Maybe you can post your save method on server so that we can analyze it?

Comment: I have issue with my req.body. it sends string instead of Array. after parsing JSON.parse(req.body.artists) and assign it to album.artists now it works as expected. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I told you 2h ago... will change the answer and accept it, please!
you are adding ' ' to define the artist when putting. Are you sure you need those ' ' ? I think it should be: artists :[{"name":"Ilesh","role":"Performer","isPrimary":true,"$$hashKey":"ob ject:227"}]; –  Alejandro Teixeira Muñoz 2 hours ago